# How to call function in nested function in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, methods, nested

I am just starting to learn programming. I am trying to define a function in python so that I wouldn't have to repeat code in my program. This program searches entries from database and displays either all entries or entries containing keyword. Here is my program stripped down for the context of this question, that works as I intended:

```
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
    

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Program')
    
    def search():
        search_window = Toplevel(root)
        search_window.title('Program - Search')
    def search_all():
        searchresult_window = Tk()
        searchresult_window.title('Program - Searchresult')

        #Checks the number of searchresults
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT COUNT() FROM entry_table')
        number = int(str(c.fetchone()).replace(",","").replace("(","").replace(")",""));

        #Gets data from database
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM entry_table')
        data = c.fetchall()
        row_count = 0

        # Scrollbar
        main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        my_scroblbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scroblbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scroblbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
        seccond_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
        my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=seccond_frame, anchor="nw")

        # Displays searchresults on screen
        for _ in range(number):
            searchresult_frame = LabelFrame(seccond_frame, pady=5, bg='yellow1')
            searchresult_frame.pack()
            data_label = Label(hakutulos_frame, text=data[row_count][1], borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=10)
            data_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

            row_count = row_count + 1

        c.close
        conn.close()
        search_window.destroy()
        searchresult_window.lift()

    def search_by_keyword():
        searchresult_window = Tk()
        searchresult_window.title('Program - Searchresult')

        #Checks the number of searchresults
        given_keyword = keyword.get()
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT() FROM entry_table WHERE subject LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR header LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR entry LIKE '%'||?||'%'",
                  (given_keyword, given_keyword, given_keyword))
        number = int(str(c.fetchone()).replace(",","").replace("(","").replace(")",""));

        #Gets data from database
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM entry_table WHERE subject LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR header LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR entry LIKE '%'||?||'%'",
                  (given_keyword, given_keyword, given_keyword))
        data = c.fetchall()
        row_count = 0

        #Scrollbar
        main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        my_scroblbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scroblbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scroblbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
        seccond_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=seccond_frame, anchor="nw")

        # Displays searchresults on screen
        for _ in range(number):
            searchresult_frame = LabelFrame(seccond_frame, pady=5, bg='yellow1')
            searchresult_frame.pack()
            data_label = Label(searchresult_frame, text=data[row_count][1], borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=10)
            data_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        c.close
        conn.close()
        search_window.destroy()
        searchresult_window.lift()

    #Show all button
    all_btn = Button(search_window, text="Show all entries", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search_all)
    all_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #Search by keyword frame (including: entry field and search button)
    search_by_keyword_frame = LabelFrame(search_window, text="Search by keyword", pady=5, bg='yellow1')
    search_by_keyword_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
    keyword = Entry(search_by_keyword_frame)
    keyword.delete(0, END)
    keyword.insert(END, str("Give Keyword"))
    keyword.grid(row=0, column=0)
    hae = Button(search_by_keyword_frame, text="SEARCH", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search_by_keyword)
    hae.grid(row=1, column=0)

    return_btn = Button(search_window, text="Return", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command =search_window.destroy)
  

      return_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
    
    
    search_btn = Button(root, text="Search", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search)
    search_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```

I realize parts #Scrollbar and #Displays Search results on screen are the exact same and I want to call a function insted of it. However it seems that no matter where I define the function (for scrollbar and Display) I always get error. Here is one example that I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Program')

def search():
search_window = Toplevel(root)
search_window.title('Program - Search')

def function1():
    # Scrollbar
    main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    my_scroblbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scroblbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scroblbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    seccond_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=seccond_frame, anchor="nw")

    # Displays searchresults on screen
    for _ in range(number):
        searchresult_frame = LabelFrame(seccond_frame, pady=5, bg='yellow1')
        searchresult_frame.pack()
        data_label = Label(hakutulos_frame, text=data[row_count][1], borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=10)
        data_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        row_count = row_count + 1

def search_all():
    searchresult_window = Tk()
    searchresult_window.title('Program - Searchresult')

    #Checks the number of searchresults
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT COUNT() FROM entry_table')
    number = int(str(c.fetchone()).replace(",","").replace("(","").replace(")",""));

    #Gets data from database
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM entry_table')
    data = c.fetchall()
    row_count = 0

    function1()

    c.close
    conn.close()
    search_window.destroy()
    searchresult_window.lift()

def search_by_keyword():
    searchresult_window = Tk()
    searchresult_window.title('Program - Searchresult')

    #Checks the number of searchresults
    given_keyword = keyword.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT() FROM entry_table WHERE subject LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR header LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR entry LIKE '%'||?||'%'",
              (given_keyword, given_keyword, given_keyword))
    number = int(str(c.fetchone()).replace(",","").replace("(","").replace(")",""));

    #Gets data from database
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM entry_table WHERE subject LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR header LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR entry LIKE '%'||?||'%'",
              (given_keyword, given_keyword, given_keyword))
    data = c.fetchall()
    row_count = 0

    function1()

    c.close
    conn.close()
    search_window.destroy()
    searchresult_window.lift()

#Show all button
all_btn = Button(search_window, text="Show all entries", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search_all)
all_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Search by keyword frame (including: entry field and search button)
search_by_keyword_frame = LabelFrame(search_window, text="Search by keyword", pady=5, bg='yellow1')
search_by_keyword_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
keyword = Entry(search_by_keyword_frame)
keyword.delete(0, END)
keyword.i

nsert(END, str("Give Keyword"))
    keyword.grid(row=0, column=0)
    hae = Button(search_by_keyword_frame, text="SEARCH", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search_by_keyword)
    hae.grid(row=1, column=0)

    return_btn = Button(search_window, text="Return", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command =search_window.destroy)
    return_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)


search_btn = Button(root, text="Search", pady=5, bg='yellow1', command=search)
search_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Here is the error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/test/venv/Testi.py", line 49, in search_all
    function1()
  File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/test/Testi.py", line 14, in function1
    main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window)
NameError: name 'searchresult_window' is not defined

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1883, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/test/venv/Testi.py", line 49, in search_all function1() File "C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/test/Testi.py", line 14, in function1 main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window) NameError: name 'searchresult_window' is not defined
```

The root error the interpreter complain about is this bit:

```
line 14, in function1 main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window) NameError: name 'searchresult_window' is not defined
```

Meaning, Python interpreter can't find the variable `searchresult_window` to use it inside function1 because that is not in function1's scope. You have defined the variable inside some other function (`search_all`) and not passing it to function1. You should either pass the variable to function1 or define the variable in a scope where function1 has access to it. I defined the variable in the global scope, this should resolve the issue.

```
searchresult_window = Tk()
searchresult_window.title('Program - Searchresult')

def function1():
    # Scrollbar
    main_frame = Frame(searchresult_window)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    my_scroblbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scroblbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scroblbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    seccond_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=seccond_frame, anchor="nw")

    # Displays searchresults on screen
    for _ in range(number):
        searchresult_frame = LabelFrame(seccond_frame, pady=5, bg='yellow1')
        searchresult_frame.pack()
        data_label = Label(hakutulos_frame, text=data[row_count][1], borderwidth=5, relief="groove", width=10)
        data_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        row_count = row_count + 1

def search_all():    
    #Checks the number of searchresults
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT COUNT() FROM entry_table')
    number = int(str(c.fetchone()).replace(",","").replace("(","").replace(")",""));

    #Gets data from database
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM entry_table')
    data = c.fetchall()
    row_count = 0

    function1()

    c.close
    conn.close()
    search_window.destroy()
    searchresult_window.lift()
```

Comment: "I defined the variable in the global scope, this should resolve the issue." I am having hard time to understand witch variable you are refering to since, there are many variables inside function1 (main_frame, my_canvas, my scrollbar, etc.). I think I understand the idea behind scoping, but maybe it is some specific mechanism I don't get. I'm sorry, I think I having a language barrier and can't understand it without conext.

Comment: searchresult_window. That's the variable with which you get the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was quite a bit more complex than I unerstood, but I got it working on my original program. In the context of this question it was about passing multiple variables into function1 (`searchresult_window, number, row_count, data`). 

I had hard time figuring it out since in my program `number` is defined by the database witch in this example peace had nothing in it. Also on my main program I had even more variables to be passed into function. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Absolutely. You can pass the variables as you did as well. I felt searchresult_window belongs in the global scope because you had it defined in one function and being used by another; thought multiple functions need access to that. Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's use your example / question and explain two options regarding Python.**

The issue is that you create *search_window* inside the method search() so it is defined only there.

Python as a programming language gives you many alternatives (like any other programming language)

**Option 1: use return**

You can return the variable from the method and then use it in other location

```
def search():
    search_window = Toplevel(root)
    search_window.title('Program - Search')
    return search_window  # i added this line at the end of the function
```

later in the code you can do this:

```
    search_window = search()
```

**Option 2: global keyword**

Python gives you an ability to update (or define) global variables from inside a method.

```
def search():
    global search_window # added ths line to define global variable
    search_window = Toplevel(root)
    search_window.title('Program - Search')
```

**Do not forget to call *search()*** somewhere below (you don't do that in your example).
From that point on, you will have a new variable named search_window. Simply approach it.

Comment: This did not solve my problem on this particular program, but I now have understanding of return and scoping. I very much aprriciate your input! It helped me in general.

Comment: i appreciate if you vote up my comment. Thanks @Heikki.

Comment: I would if I could. It seems that I don't have the reputation in Stack overflow to do that yet, but I'll try to remember this when I do.

Comment: @Heikki maybe you have the ability now? :) kindly reminder